# I am getting different output while solving this program manually

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops, output

As an assignment, I have to speculate the output of this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void change (char* state, int &s)
{
    int b = s;
    for (int x = 0; s>=0; x++, s--)
    if ((x+s)%2)
        *(state+x) = toupper(*(state+b-x));
}

int main ( )
{
    char s[] = "Punjab";
    int b = strlen(s) - 1;
    change (s, b);
    std::cout<<s<<"#"<<b;
}
```

According to my book, when compiled and executed, this program should output:

```
BAJJAB#-1
```

The problem is that my guess, executing the code in my mind, would be

```
BAJNUP#-1
```

instead.

I am making a mistake somewhere, but where?

Comment: What do you mean with "solving it manually"? That you do it all on paper?

Comment: yup buddy, i have this question to find the output in my exam.

Comment: you may not be considering that you are overwriting values in `state` and using them later

Comment: Remember that the `change` function modifies the string in place. In the very first iteration it will replace the leading `'P'` with the `'B'`. The `'P'` will no longer exist in the string.

Comment: Aside: There is some **horrible** names here. `s` is the text in `main` and the (barely used) reverse offset in `change`. Most of the locals are single letters... ugh

Answer (score 2):

While running code on paper, it's a good idea to keep track of the values your variables take.

This `int b = strlen(s) - 1;` gives 5.

Inside `change()` now,

`b` holds the value of `s`, which is 5.

Now focus here:

```
for (int x = 0; s>=0; x++, s--)
  if ((x+s)%2)
    *(state+x) = toupper(*(state+b-x));
```

`x == 0, s == 5`, where their sum is not even, thus `%2` will not result in 0, resulting in the body of the if statement to execute and write `state[5]` to `state[0]`.

Now `x` is increased by 1, and `s` is decreased by 1, since `s >= 0` evaluates to true.

And so on...After you are done with your paper-run, you may want to print your variables at every step of your program (when you actually run it on a computer), and compare them with every step you made on paper.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void change (char* state, int &s)
{
    int b = s;
    for (int x = 0; s>=0; x++, s--)
    {
        std::cout << "x = " << x << ", s = " << s << ", x + s = " << x + s << ", (x + s) % 2 = " << (x + s) % 2 << "\n";
        if ((x+s)%2)
        {
            std::cout << "state[" << x << "] = state[" << b - x << "]\n";
            *(state+x) = toupper(*(state+b-x));
        }
        std::cout << "state = \"" << state << "\"\n";
    }
}

int main ( )
{
    char s[] = "Punjab";
    int b = strlen(s) - 1;
    change (s, b);
    std::cout<<s<<"#"<<b;
}
```

Output:

```
x = 0, s = 5, x + s = 5, (x + s) % 2 = 1
state[0] = state[5]
state = "Bunjab"
x = 1, s = 4, x + s = 5, (x + s) % 2 = 1
state[1] = state[4]
state = "BAnjab"
x = 2, s = 3, x + s = 5, (x + s) % 2 = 1
state[2] = state[3]
state = "BAJjab"
x = 3, s = 2, x + s = 5, (x + s) % 2 = 1
state[3] = state[2]
state = "BAJJab"
x = 4, s = 1, x + s = 5, (x + s) % 2 = 1
state[4] = state[1]
state = "BAJJAb"
x = 5, s = 0, x + s = 5, (x + s) % 2 = 1
state[5] = state[0]
state = "BAJJAB"
BAJJAB#-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your book is correct. Your manual solution is wrong because you don't take into account the memory assignments you do inside your for loop.

After the 3rd iteration, inside your `char` array you have `BAJJAB` because the last 3 letters have replaced the first 3. Now in your 4th iteration what the code does is taking the 3rd letter, J, and replacing the 4th letter. Then replacing the 5th letter with the 2nd and so on. But look! Now the 1-3 letters are not PUN but have already been changed from previous iterations to BAJ. That's why the printed word ends up being a symmetric word